# How to properly create a mobile version on "m.website.com"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mobile, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

We want to put our mobile version **m.website.com**. As our app is running on Amazon EC2 instances, we'll probably need to create a new instance for the **m** subdomain and copy the whole project to this subdomain-space.

I don't think this is very efficient - is there any way to have all ours code on our current EC2 instance (on **website.com**) and when someone will access our project from **m.website.com**, then would be served code from **website.com** that would be optimised for mobile?

We're doing it for the first time, so we're not experienced here with the server setup.

Thank you all for advance.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your customizations are all within the view of your app, you can switch the layout in your `application_controller.rb` depending on the subdomain that you are receiving from the client's request:

```
layout :layout_by_subdomain

def layout_by_subdomain
  if request.subdomain.start_with("m")
    layout "mobile"
  else
    layout "application"
  end
end
```

And in your `app/views/layouts` you will keep the `application.html.erb` and add a `mobile.html.erb`

Personally I think the better way to go with a responsive layout for your site. Then the device's screen width determines whether the mobile version will be shown or not. It might not be an option on your end, but that's the way it would be "done right".

Comment: But this requires having all code on the subdomain **m.website.com**, right? (so the code will be stored as on **m.website.com** as on **website.com**)

Comment: No, you can map m.website.com and website.com to the same server via the cname entry.

Answer (score 0):

You don't give details of your web stack, but most web servers can allow you to run the same code for multiple different host names.

So you'd update your DNS so that www.website.com, m.website.com and website.com all point to the same server (A record for a single IP, or CNAME for a load balancer.  Route53 has something called an Alias record to allow you to point a top-level domain at a load balancer).

For apache, you can add a ServerAlias for each additional host name. nginx allows multiple names and wildcards in the server_name value, and most other web servers will have some mechanism for handling this.

Then you can implement @Christopher Eicke's suggestion for handling different layout, if you decide you don't want to implement a responsive design.